# Horizontal scrollview inside custum UItableviewcell not scrolling, even go down in tableview and reload the cell then it will scroll , why?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, ipad

------------------------I am returning my custum cell-----------

```
    AnotationImageTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"AnotationImageTableViewCell"];
    cell.ImageArray=ImageArray;
    [cell displayScrollviewWithImages];

    //NSLog(@"%f",cell.scrollV.contentSize.width);

    return cell;
```

-------------------------set up scrollview inside cell---------------------

-(void)displayScrollviewWithImages{

```
_scrollV.bounces = NO;
_scrollV.scrollsToTop = NO;
_scrollV.alwaysBounceHorizontal=NO;
_scrollV.alwaysBounceVertical=NO;
_scrollV.pagingEnabled=YES;

_imageV.placeholderImage=[UIImage imageNamed:@"noImage"];
_imageV.imageURL=[NSURL URLWithString:@""];


[_scrollV setContentSize:CGSizeMake(_scrollV.frame.size.width*_ImageArray.count,_scrollV.frame.size.height)];

    if(!IS_COUNT_ZERO(_ImageArray)){

        for (int i=0; i<_ImageArray.count; i++)
        {
            EGOImageView *imageVi = [[EGOImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(_scrollV.frame.size.width*i, _scrollV.frame.origin.y, _scrollV.frame.size.width, _scrollV.frame.size.height)];
            imageVi.placeholderImage=[UIImage imageNamed:@"noImage"];
            imageVi.imageURL=[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@%@",HTTP,API_URL,[_ImageArray objectAtIndex:i]?[_ImageArray objectAtIndex:i]:@""]];
            imageVi.tag = 100+i;
            [_pageControl setNumberOfPages:_ImageArray.count];
            [_scrollV addSubview:imageVi];

        }


    }
    else
    {
     _pageControl.hidden=YES;
    }
```

}

Comment: start your for loop with 0 and why you have do setup outside the for loop not needed

Comment: for your goal collection view is better option in cell

Comment: Hi Mike...even we changed like this..actual problem is still there...the scrollview as well as page control is not responding to the user even until we scrollview down and up.